# Communicating with Android TaskManager

Tags: android

I have a non responsive app on android which I need to kill and let the user start it manually. If I use KillBackgroundTask in android it simply restarts the task.

Is there a way to direct the builtin task manager to kill the task (using package name)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```